# Get the biggest number "n" in an array that occurs "n" times

Tags: java, arrays

Title sums it up.
For example `{2,3,3,3,1}` would return 3, `{2,2,4,4,4}` would return 2;
In my code I only get the biggest number that occurs n times. If 3 would occur 2 times and 2 would occur 2 times the program should return 2 but in my code it return 0.

```
public class arrays {

   public static int NmalN(int[] arr) {
       int max = 0;
       int counter = 1;
       for (int i=0; i<arr.length;) {
           if (arr[i]>max) {
               max = arr[i];
               i++;
           }
           else i++;
       }
       for(int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++) {
           if (arr[j]==max) {
               counter++;
               j++;
           }
           else {
               j++;
           }
       }

       if(max == counter) { 
           return counter;
       }
       else return 0; 
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int [] arr = {1,2,3,3,2,};
       System.out.println("answer: "+ (NmalN(arr)));

   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `j` twice for each iteration in your second loop? One in the loop definition, other in the if/else. Also, your first loop would've found a max of 4, and second loop would find that 4 hasn't occurred 4 times, so returns 0. You don't take 2 into account anywhere.

Comment: Try using `Map` to store the the element as the key and the number of occurrences as the value. You can do this with one iteration over the array. Then after storing the necessary information. See if the key matches value (the number of occurrences) and just need to check if the number is bigger than the max number you are keeping track of

Answer (score 0):

As I read your code, you find the biggest number in the array, `max`. If that number occurs exactly `max` times, no more no less, you return it, otherwise you return 0. When 3 occurs only twice, you should probably try with 2, then with 1, etc. rather than just returning 0. Also think: is it OK if the number occurs more than `max` times?

Your loop for finding `max` looks fine (though convention would place `i++` inside `for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` and not inside the loop). After that you need a `for` loop to count down from `max` to 0, for each number `n` in that range checking if it occurs at least `n` times. You way of counting is almost correct, but as Vasan said in a comment, you are doing `j++` both in `for(int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++)` *and* in the loop, that is, twice, so remove the one inside the loop. Whenever you find that `counter >= n`, return `n`. If not earlier, it will happen when `n` is 0, since 0 is always present 0 times.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a worst-case O(n^2) solution? I know OP doesn't say anything about complexity but worth adding I suppose. There are O(n) and O(n log n) solutions.

Comment: Yes, @Vasan, I deliberately ignored time complexity and just tried to show a way that wasn’t too far from the OP’s own code and that would work for arrays of 5 elements (and probably 500 elements). Maybe I should have mentioned that the solution isn’t supposed to scale. On the other hand, there’s something right about my approach: write simple and readable code that works, and only if performance turns out to be a bottleneck, consider smarter alternatives.

Comment: @Vasan, my O(n) solution is [here](https://www.ideone.com/zk3F2Q), but that’s not the one the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class find_Biggest_Num_N_In_Array_Occures_N_times {
     public static int Solution(int[] ar){
     int[] counter= new int[ar.length];
     Arrays.fill(counter, 0);

     for(int i=0; i<ar.length;i++){
     int pos=ar[i];
     counter[pos]++;
     }

    for(int j=ar.length-1;j>=1;j--){
      if(counter[j]==j){
        return j;
      }
    }
    return -1;
 }

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(Solution(new int[]{1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,3,5,5,5,5,5,1}));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int solution(Integer[] intArray) {
       int result = 0;
       Arrays.sort(intArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
       for (int i=0; i<intArray.length;i++) {
           int count = 0;
           for(int j=0;j<intArray.length;j++) {
               if(intArray[i]==intArray[j]) {
                   count++;
               }
           }
           if(count == intArray[i]) {
               result = intArray[i];
               break;
           }
       }
       return result; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, it'll be like this

```
function getLargestFrequency(arr) {
    let frequency = {};

    // Count frequency of each number
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let num = arr[i];
        if (frequency[num]) {
            frequency[num]++;
        } else {
            frequency[num] = 1;
        }
    }

    let maxFrequency = 0;
    let maxNum;
    for (let num in frequency) {
        if (frequency[num] > maxFrequency) {
            maxFrequency = frequency[num];
            maxNum = num;
        }
    }
    // Initialize the maxFrequencyCount with maxFrequency
    let maxFrequencyCount = maxFrequency;
    // Iterate over the frequency object
    for (let num in frequency) {
        if (frequency[num] === maxFrequencyCount) {
            // If the current number's frequency count is equal to maxFrequencyCount, return it
            return num;
        }
    }
    // If no number with the highest frequency count is found, return 0
    return 0;
}
```

and you can see the output

```
let array1 = [2,3,3,3,1];
let result1 = getLargestFrequency(array1);
console.log(result1); // should return 3

let array2 = [2,2,4,4,4];
let result2 = getLargestFrequency(array2);
console.log(result2); // should return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work
`    import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class find_Biggest_Num_N_In_Array_Occures_N_times {
 public static int Solution(int[] ar){
 Arrays.sort(ar);
 int maxElement = ar[ar.length -1];
 int[] counter= new int[maxElement + 1];
 Arrays.fill(counter, 0);

 for(int i=0; i<ar.length;i++){
 int pos=ar[i];
 counter[pos]++;
 }

for(int j=ar.length-1;j>=1;j--){
  if(counter[j]==j){
    return j;
  }
}
return -1;
```

}
}`